# Sobre a versão mobile depois da atualização

Tags: suporte, layout

Bom, o meu smartphone é um Galaxy Y (não me julguem =P)

Eu não sei se é só aqui, mas no navegador padrão há algum bugs: os ícones de notificações ficam invisíveis, o botão "Perguntar" não aparece, a largura da página é maior que a do aparelho.

No Opera Mini os problemas se resolvem, com exceção da largura da página, mas o tamanho da fonte e ícones ficam gigantes.

Como ninguém mais reclamou, talvez seja uma incompatibilidade com versões antigas do Android. A verdade é que antes funcionava muito bem.

Comment: Eu reclamei da falta de espaço para o link de perguntar, aqui: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234717/mobile-web-refresher/234725#234725. O resto não acontece no meu celular (que é de outra marca e modelo).