# Bug na versão mobile

Tags: bug, suporte

Há uma questão similar ([Sobre a versão mobile depois da atualização](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1634)), passei pelos mesmos problemas, mas comigo foi além.

1# Os links não abrem, é necessário abrir em nova janela ou aba.
2# Os votos estão muito difíceis de marcar. Quando clicado o voto não computa e/ou marca errado.

No segundo caso, quando ocorreu eu não pude desfazer o DOWN-VOTE, precisei editar a resposta explicando o motivo para poder desfazer o erro.

Estou dando um feedback da minha experiência com mobile:
Aparelho: `Galaxy Y`
Navegador: `Opera mini`

Também testei o APP, mas a sessão terminava muito rápido e era complicado acessar o `SO-PT`.

Answer (score 1):

Sou o autor da outra pergunta e também tenho um Galaxy Y. Consegui resolver o problema 100% instalando o [UC Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UCMobile.intl&hl=pt_BR). Outros sites, como o Facebook e Twitter também funcionam melhor nele.

Na tela de configurações do UC Browser, recomendo algumas mudanças:

- Desative a "navegação em nuvem" para o Wi-Fi, mantenha ativado apenas para 2G/3G.
- Configure ele para abrir a versão para smartphones dos sites. Por *default* ele abre a versão WAP (para celulares simples) de certos sites como o Facebook e Twitter.

Espero ter ajudado. Quem tem aparelho de pobre sofre. =P

Comment: Era sua questão mesmo :) Não conhecia nenhuma dessas configurações que você falou - totalmente ignorante com o celular. Vou testar e depois digo o que houve. Você teve problema com os votos também?

Comment: As fechas dos votos no *browser* padrão do Android não apareciam, assim como alguns ícones. No UC Browser funciona 100%.

Comment: Vou testar o outro Opera também para ver se melhora. Me amarro no `Galaxy Y` e o Opera para PC é show :)

Comment: Usem o Chrome que fica impecável.

Comment: @JorgeB. O Chrome só está disponível, se eu não me engano, a partir do Android 4.0. O Galaxy Y possui o 2.3.

Comment: Estou no Opera brigando para enviar comentario... Vou trocar, mas o UC Browser tem 12 mb, nao tenho memoria pa ele.